# Drupal 7: Views search not returning correct results for multiple term searches

Tags: views, search

I've inherited a search form built using Views. When searching for one term the results are correct, and when searching for multiple terms enclosed in quotes the results are correct (although with duplicate entries), but when searching for multiple terms without quotes the results are not as expected.

You can view the search form at http://texasfortstrail.com. Search for fort, fort concho, and "fort concho" for different result sets.

Thoughts on what could be causing the discrepancies? I'm using Drupal 7.14 and Views 7.x-3.5.

Here's the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'search_results';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Search Results';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Search Results';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['wrapper_class'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['default_field_elements'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_type'] = 'h3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_class'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Domain Access: Domain ID */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['gid']['table'] = 'domain_access';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
/* Sort criterion: Search: Score */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['id'] = 'score';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['table'] = 'search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['field'] = 'score';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Search: Search Terms */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['id'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['table'] = 'search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['field'] = 'keys';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['default_action'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['keys']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'about_us_home' => 'about_us_home',
  'about_us_page' => 'about_us_page',
  'city' => 'city',
  'event' => 'event',
  'home_page_content' => 'home_page_content',
  'our_stories' => 'our_stories',
  'our_stories_home' => 'our_stories_home',
  'page' => 'page',
  'partners' => 'partners',
  'partners_home' => 'partners_home',
  'pya_home' => 'pya_home',
  'pya_page' => 'pya_page',
  'site' => 'site',
  'thc_theme' => 'thc_theme',
);
/* Filter criterion: Domain Access: Available on current domain */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['id'] = 'current_all';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['table'] = 'domain_access';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['field'] = 'current_all';

/* Display: Search Results */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Search Results', 'default_results');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_type'] = 'h3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_class'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Short Description */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['id'] = 'field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['table'] = 'field_data_field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['field'] = 'field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['alter']['max_length'] = '100';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['alter']['trim'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_type'] = 'p';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['type'] = 'text_plain';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['sorts'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Search: Score */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['id'] = 'score';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['table'] = 'search_index';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['field'] = 'score';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['score']['order'] = 'DESC';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Domain Access: Available on current domain */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['id'] = 'current_all';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['table'] = 'domain_access';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['field'] = 'current_all';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['value'] = '1';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'about_us_home' => 'about_us_home',
  'about_us_page' => 'about_us_page',
  'city' => 'city',
  'event' => 'event',
  'home_page_content' => 'home_page_content',
  'our_stories' => 'our_stories',
  'our_stories_home' => 'our_stories_home',
  'page' => 'page',
  'partners' => 'partners',
  'partners_home' => 'partners_home',
  'pya_home' => 'pya_home',
  'pya_page' => 'pya_page',
  'site' => 'site',
  'thc_theme' => 'thc_theme',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'search/node/%';

/* Display: Other Domain Results */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Other Domain Results', 'other_domain_results');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Link */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['id'] = 'view_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['table'] = 'views_entity_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['field'] = 'view_node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['view_node']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['path'] = '[view_node]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['absolute'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['strip_tags'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_type'] = 'h3';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_class'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Short Description */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['id'] = 'field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['table'] = 'field_data_field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['field'] = 'field_desc_short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['alter']['max_length'] = '100';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['alter']['trim'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_type'] = 'p';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_desc_short']['type'] = 'text_plain';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'about_us_home' => 'about_us_home',
  'about_us_page' => 'about_us_page',
  'city' => 'city',
  'event' => 'event',
  'home_page_content' => 'home_page_content',
  'our_stories' => 'our_stories',
  'our_stories_home' => 'our_stories_home',
  'page' => 'page',
  'partners' => 'partners',
  'partners_home' => 'partners_home',
  'pya_home' => 'pya_home',
  'pya_page' => 'pya_page',
  'site' => 'site',
  'thc_theme' => 'thc_theme',
);
/* Filter criterion: Domain Access: Available on current domain */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['id'] = 'current_all';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['table'] = 'domain_access';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['field'] = 'current_all';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['current_all']['value'] = '0';
/* Filter criterion: Domain Access: Domain ID */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['gid']['id'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['gid']['table'] = 'domain_access';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['gid']['field'] = 'gid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['gid']['operator'] = 'not in';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['gid']['value'] = array(
  '***CURRENT_DOMAIN***' => '***CURRENT_DOMAIN***',
  1 => '1',
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'search/node/%';
```

Comment: Consider adding the results of your two example searches to this post.  Otherwise once this is fixed, the URL will no longer be useful to future searchers.

Comment: I have the same issue. The code shown on http://drupal.org/node/1950512#comment-7263844 fixed the duplicate nodes issue.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue:

- https://drupal.org/node/1615438
- https://drupal.org/node/1948510