# Views-based search not returning expected results

Tags: views

I've got a Views-based search interface for my Drupal 7 site. I'm noticing when I do a text-based search using the 'search terms' (Search: search terms) field it's only returning partial results.

I've already ensured the search index was rebuilt and cron was run.

My View is set to show all records by default. My other drop-down filters work fine.

It's just the search terms field that only returns partial results. Specifically if you search for a phrase it returns only results from one value of a field list...

Example: if I type 'the grantsmanship center' (without single quotes) it does NOT return all the correct results. However, if I type just 'grantsmanship' (without quotes) it does return the results correctly. Also if I type 'grantsmanship center' without quotes it returns the correct results. If I type "the grantsmanship center" (with quotes) it returns the correct results but puts only 2 items per page (for some reason I don't understand)...it's set to return 10 items per page. All the others return those results paged correctly.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May depend on your version of Views, as there appear to be some known issues, depending on the Drupal Views version.

- [Drupal 7: Views search not returning correct results for multiple term searches](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/drupal-7-views-search-not-returning-correct-results-for-multiple-term-searches)
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1615438
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1948510